# How to change the overlayLoadingTemplate in ag Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am using **Ag Grid v11.0** with **angular 1.x**. After the grid is rendered, I want to make an action ( ex: save the grid items ) changing the **overlayLoadingTemplate** property in order to display a different message ( ex: *Saving ... please wait* ).

```
$scope.save = save;

var _overlayLoadingTemplate = '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">Please wait while your items are loading</span>';
var _overlaySaveTemplate = '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center">Saving...</span>';

$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: [/*stuff*/],
  overlayLoadingTemplate: _overlayLoadingTemplate,
};

function save () {
  $scope.gridOptions.overlayLoadingTemplate = _overlaySaveTemplate;

  $scope.gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay();

  /* call service and get response logic here */

  $scope.gridOptions.api.hideOverlay();
}
```

---

The **overlayLoadingTemplate** property is not being changed, is the initial one: _overlayLoadingTemplate. I didn't find any set methods like **setOverlayLoadingTemplate**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overlays cannot be updated in the way that you want I'm afraid. The Loading Overlay and the No Rows Overlay can be changed from the default, but this is done at initialisation time and cannot be changed again.

If you wish to display application specific overlays I'm afraid you'll need to provide an implementation of this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.  I needed to change text in the overlay template of the child grid in a master-detail scenario.

In your overlay template, create placeholder elements that you swap out with content **right before** you call `showLoadingOverlay`

```
$scope.save = save;

var _overlayLoadingTemplate = '<span class="ag-overlay-loading-center"><span id="js-overlay-text">Please wait while your items are loading...</span></span>';

$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: [/*stuff*/],
  overlayLoadingTemplate: _overlayLoadingTemplate,
};

function save () {

  document.getElementById("js-overlay-text").innerText = "Saving...";
  $scope.gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay();

  /* call service and get response logic here */

  $scope.gridOptions.api.hideOverlay();
}
```

Comment: if is it no problem executing code outside angular scope, this will approach will work :)

Comment: Shouldn’t matter if it’s Angular or vanilla JavaScript.